# ConnectionRefused in windows 10 IoT

Tags: c#, tcp, uwp, windows-10-iot-core, dhcp

I've created an DHCP server and I've added a TCP server. When I send a message at address IPv4 of the DHCP server, the client answer with: `ConnectionRefused`.

I've set the property to true

```
DataSocket = new DatagramSocket();
DataSocket.Control.MulticastOnly = true;
```

This code running to boot of the app UWP:

```
private void Start()
{
  if (this.StatusButton.Content.ToString().Equals(AVVIA))
  {
    this.ViewModel.Action = "AVVIO DEL SERVER DHCP IN CORSO...";
    RunServer();
    this.StatusButton.Content = UPDATE;
    Task.Run(async () => 
    {
      await Task.Delay(DELAY);
      Server = new Server();
      Server.StartServer();
     });
  }

  ... ... ...

private void RunServer()
{
  IPAddress iPAddress;

  DhcpServer = new ScaemDhcp.DhcpServer();
  iPAddress = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 192, 168, 1, 101 });
  DhcpServer.Run(iPAddress, DNS, SUB_MASK, SERVER_IDENTIFIER, ROUTER_IP);
}
```

```
public void Run(IPAddress iPAddress, string dns, string subnetMask, string serverIdentifier, string routerIP)
{
  var server = new Dhcp(iPAddress);
  server.ServerName = dns;
  server.BroadcastAddress = IPAddress.Broadcast.ToString();
  server.OnDataReceived += (sender, dhcpRequest) =>
  {
    try
    {
      var type = dhcpRequest.GetMsgType();
      var ip = iPAddress;
      var replyOptions = new DhcpReplyOptions();
      replyOptions.SubnetMask = IPAddress.Parse(subnetMask);
      replyOptions.DomainName = server.ServerName;
      replyOptions.ServerIdentifier = IPAddress.Parse(serverIdentifier);
      replyOptions.RouterIP = IPAddress.Parse(routerIP);
      replyOptions.DomainNameServers = new IPAddress[]
      {IPAddress.Parse("8.8.8.8"), IPAddress.Parse("8.8.4.4")};

      if (type == DhcpMsgType.DHCPDISCOVER)
      {
        dhcpRequest.SendDHCPReply(DhcpMsgType.DHCPOFFER, ip, replyOptions);
      }
      if (type == DhcpMsgType.DHCPREQUEST)
      {
        dhcpRequest.SendDHCPReply(DhcpMsgType.DHCPACK, ip, replyOptions);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { }
 };
 server.Start();
}

... ...

public async void StartServer()
{
  try
  {
    var streamSocketListener = new StreamSocketListener();

    streamSocketListener.ConnectionReceived += this.StreamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived;

    await streamSocketListener.BindServiceNameAsync(PORT.ToString());
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       ... ...
```

Comment: TCP doesn't support Multicast.  Multicast is only UDP.

Comment: I've added this support (Multicast) for test all solution possible (I'm in desperate mode)...

Comment: Multicast is Broadcast and you cannot connect.  Multicast only works for IP 224.X.X.X to 239.X.X.X.  You can have UDP Broadcast for Multicast and Non Multicast.  DCHP uses ports 67 and 68 which is probably blocked by your virus checker or firewall.  SEe Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol

Comment: I've removed Multicast and like result I've that the DHCP server work fine, but my TCP Server in Win 10 IoT not work at all. I've connected Raspberry (Win 10 IoT) with my PC via Ethernet. The result is: PC require and obtain an IPv4, GW, etc... as setted in DHCP server. Then I run (in PC) a client TCP for sending a message to my Raspberry (Win 10 IoT), here I've in execution a TCP server. The result of the client is: ConnectionRefused.

Comment: DCHP is UDP Broadcast. IP: source=0.0.0.0 (Server) ; destination=255.255.255.255 (broadcast IP)
UDP: source port=68; destination port=67

Comment: Sorry, I wrong to espetate the problem. In my Raspberry (Windows 10 IoT) I've created an app UWP with two server: DHCP server and a TCP server. The DHCP server work fine; it's the TCP server that not work. The TCP server it's created like StartServer() and the communication port is 5037.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From comment by @Michale Xu - MSFT

@Nicolò, I have given a response on [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/514c15bd-f7aa-4af2-9153-cdbce4d6b0d8/connectionrefused-in-windows-10-iot?forum=WindowsIoT#da6be1cb-9cb2-4b27-8a64-5ed0c9e2eb02) about the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to check if you have add the capability **[Private Networks (Client & Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations)**, this capability provides inbound and outbound access to home and work networks through the firewall. Please refer to this document([enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets#build-a-basic-tcp-socket-client-and-server)).

And then, you need to check if the port is available, you can add the rules for port 5037 in firewall, please try with following command.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="5037 In" dir=in protocol=TCP localport=5037 action=Allow
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="5037 Out" dir=out protocol=TCP localport=5037 action=Allow
```

Comment: I have no good news. I begin to doubt the client that runs in the PC. Place part of the code: ```await streamSocket.ConnectAsync("192.168.1.101", "5037");```

Comment: @Nicolò, have you referred to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets)? This topic shows how to use the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) socket classes to create a server and client.

Comment: Yes, I've referred to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets), but only the client TCP it's execute in my PC.

Comment: @Nicolò, i want to confirm something with you. 1. Have you used ping command to check if the network is fine, the device is reachable from the client on PC? 2. When the client connected the server, is there some exception thrown, please provide the error information. You can try to use another socket test tool to connect the server/port. If possible, please share your project so that i can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Please try to run the command `netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all` on Windows IoT Core, to confirm the rules for port 5073 are configured.

Comment: 1. ping corrected from PC to Raspberry (Win 10 IoT). 2. The errors information are: - Message: _Connection could not be established. Persistent rejection of the target computer._ - StackTrace: _at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at ScaemClientSocket.ClientSocket.<ClientReadWrite>d__3.MoveNext()_. I've tested with PuTTy and I've equivalent result: connection refused.

Comment: Please try to run the [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket/cs) to test this issue.BTW, which build Windows iot core did you test on? You can try to re-flash windows iot core to the SD card. If the issue could not be fixed, please feel free and let me know.

Comment: I've execute the netsh command and the result is [here](http://collabedit.com/waqw4)

Comment: Did you check if there some prohibition rule in the router?

Comment: I've noted that if I use as IP address the IPv4 returned by ipconfig command, the server ([sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket/cs) not is achievable; if I use the IP address returned by IoT Dashboard, it's achievable. I've thincked that this worked for my app DHCP/TCP, but IoT Dashboard show IP 192.168.1.101 that's equivalent of my IPv4 (by ipconfig). For more info I've configured the DHCP server in this manner: [here](http://collabedit.com/ga3t4). Note1: I work with direct connection Raspberry - PC via Ethernet.

Comment: Note2: When I run my app DHCP/TCP the Windows Device Portal isn't achievable; for to rend achievable the Raspberry, I should connect all in my router.

Comment: @Nicolò, I have given a response on MSDN forum about the similar [issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/514c15bd-f7aa-4af2-9153-cdbce4d6b0d8/connectionrefused-in-windows-10-iot?forum=WindowsIoT).

Comment: is my post. I posted on MSDN because I thought there was a different local time and to not stop and look for a solution, I posted on MSDN...

Comment: I've posted my project in [gitgub](https://github.com/devIot14/DTServer/tree/master/DtServer)